# Hide controls and disable right click on HTML5 video on Safari

Tags: html, video, safari

I'm working on a project that includes a video tag. users can full screen this video. I'm disabling the right click with the following code:

```
document.oncontextmenu = document.body.oncontextmenu = function () {
        return false;
    };
```

In full screen mode, right click is disabled on Chrome and Firefox but on Safari I still get the right click menu (in full screen mode). How can I solve this?

I also need to disable the controls on in full screen mode. The following code does it for Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. Any suggestions please?

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
        display: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: bc it's a requirement in my project... Users are not supposed to seek while watching the video ...

Comment: I used -webkit-media-controls on Safari and it removed the controls but it also removed the subtitle <track> ... which is not the case for Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Safari 16.2 not work
MacOS 13.3, Safari 16.4 work
Safari 16.2 not work
MacOS 13.3, Safari 16.4 work
Safari 16.2 not work
MacOS 13.3, Safari 16.4 work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).