# Disable right click on html5 video perfectly

Tags: javascript, html, video, safari, fullscreen

Firstly, I never intend to prevent being download, but at least I'd like to disable context menu.
I searched and found this post: 
[Prevent HTML5 video from being downloaded (right-click saved)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756837/prevent-html5-video-from-being-downloaded-right-click-saved)

The simplest way is to add this:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

But it doesn't work with Safari while showing video in fullscreen.

So, how can I disable right click on a vidoe in Safari's fullscreen?
Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

By the way,
[Hide controls and disable right click on HTML5 video on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943032/hide-controls-and-disable-right-click-on-html5-video-on-safari)
mentioned, but yet hasn't been solved.

Comment: Have you tried video::-webkit-media-controls {
        display: none !important;
    }

Comment: I can't test this, but would adding an event listener, then using `event.preventDefault()` work?

Comment: @Parag Bhayani: If "video::-webkit-media-controls" is added, people even can't enter fullscreen.

Comment: @JoeD I tried <video controls oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault();">, just same as <... oncontextmenu="return false;">.

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992645/disable-right-clicking-in-html5-video/47625557#47625557